# Segmentation fault when starting G-WAN 3.12.26 32-bit on linux fc14

Tags: virtualization, out-of-memory, g-wan, hypervisor

I have a fc14 32 bit system with 2.6.35.13 custom compiled kernel.
When I try to start G-wan I get a "Segmentation fault".I've made no changes, just downloaded and unpacked the files from g-wan site.

In the log file I have:
"[Wed Dec 26 16:39:04 2012 GMT] Available network interfaces (16)"
which is not true, on the machine i have around 1k interfaces mostly ppp interfaces.

I think  the crash has something to do with detecting interfaces/ip addresses because in the log after the above line  I have 16 lines with ip's belonging to the fc14 machine and after that about 1k lines  with "0.0.0.0" or "random" ip addresses.

I ran gwan 3.3.7 64-bit on a fc16 with about the same number of interfaces and had no problem,well it still reported a wrong number of interfaces (16) but it did not crashed and in the log file i got only 16 lines with the ip addresses belonging to the fc16 machine.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What version of GLIBC do you have? At least 2.3.4 is required and 2.7 if you are using bandwidth shaping.

Comment: I am also having Seg. Fault. It will only work for me when I remove the maintenance script.

Comment: Same problem within archlinux (up to date)

Comment: I'm using GLIBC v2.16 ...

Comment: Mine:  Glibc: 2.13 (stable).Tried also without the maintenance script..same crash

Comment: What about sending your **logs/gwan.log** file to G-WAN's team like you have been invited repeatedly to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have around 1k interfaces mostly ppp interfaces

Only the first 16 will be listed as this information becomes irrelevant with more interfaces (the intent was to let users find why a listen attempt failed).

This is probably the long 1K list, many things have changed internally after the allocator was redesigned from scratch. Thank you for reporting the bug.

I also confirm the comment which says that the maintenance script crashes. Thanks for that.

Note that bandwidth shaping will be modified to avoid the newer Linux syscalls so the GLIBC 2.7 requirement will be waved.

> ...with a custom compiled kernel

As a general rule, check again on a standard system like Debian 6.x before asking a question: there is room enough for trouble with a known system - there's no need to add custom system components.

Thank you all for the tons(!) of emails received these two last days about the new release!

Comment: G-wan reports  Glibc: 2.13 (stable)
 I understand your requirement for testing on a standard system but I need it working on my systems as it allready did.
 For me it would be ok to have an older  version of g-wan but on g-wan site i find only the latest version.
Thanks

Comment: A new release is published to fix every newly signaled bug(s) and new FAQ entries are added to explain CPU requirements, etc. At this pace, the few issues will be fixed within a few days - that's why your feedback is important.

Comment: I tried the new version and still no luck:

# ./gwan

loading

[c___5] mp: out of memory

From logs:

# more logs/gwan.log

[Thu Jan 17 21:22:26 2013 GMT] memory footprint: 1.25 MiB(null)

[Thu Jan 17 21:22:26 2013 GMT] Host /usr/local/gwan/0.0.0.0_8080/#0.0.0.0

[Thu Jan 17 21:22:26 2013 GMT] [c___5] mp: out of memory


[Thu Jan 17 21:22:26 2013 GMT] [c___6] mp: out of memory

But i have around 800 MB free on the system

Comment: You have most probably restricted your environment with an **hypervisor** (Xen, VMWare, etc.): **you don't *really* have a 6-core CPU and only 800MB RAM** (that's most unlikely). Send us your **gwan.log** file so we can check what's wrong.

Comment: gwan_linux32-bit]# cat logs/gwan.log    
[Fri Jan 18 21:59:33 2013 GMT] memory footprint: 1.27 MiB(null)    
[Fri Jan 18 21:59:33 2013 GMT] Host /usr/local/gwan_linux32-bit/0.0.0.0_8080/#0.0.0.0     
[Fri Jan 18 21:59:33 2013 GMT] [c___4] mp: out of memory  

[Fri Jan 18 21:59:33 2013 GMT] [c___6] mp: out of memory  

[root@localhost gwan_linux32-bit]# free -m  
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached  
Mem:          3294       2662        632          0        140       2065 ... sorry for the format of the text..

Comment: (1) that's the same *useless* info as above and (2) you should **email us the whole /logs/gwan.log file** as previously requested (if your goal is to resolve your problem).

Comment: Sorry for the late answer..That's all i have in my log file.
Today I had some time to play with strace and i found a strange line:
sysinfo({uptime=2096474, loads=[1088, 1440, 2976] totalram=843322, freeram=31500...
..and the system has 3G RAM. Also i was able to run without problem gwan on a fc14
with 2.6.35.14-106 kernel.

Comment: The only difference that I see between the two fc14 machines is that on the fc14
 on which gwan claims that it has no memory when I do from c :
 struct sysinfo SYSINFO; sysinfo(&SYSINFO)

 SYSINFO.mem_unit=4096, on the ok fc14 machine SYSINFO.mem_unit=1.

 I'm not a c programmer..but could it be that mem_unit is not used for calculating
 the available RAM on the system?
thanks

Comment: **mem_units** is used properly. Again, having access to the log file that we asked would help to answer your question since it is crystal clear that you are **constraining G-WAN in a virtualized environment**.

Comment: it's nothing virtual in there.. I could not afford it .. about 700 mbps of tunneled traffic is flowing through the machine so I need mostly processor not memory. Anyways gwan 4.2.7 works on it..so  thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar "Segmentation fault" error; mine happens any time I go to 9+GB of RAM. Exact same machine at 8GB works fine, and 10GB doesn't even report an error, it just returns to the prompt.

Interesting behavior... Have you tried adjusting the amount of RAM to see what happens?

(running G-WAN 4.1.25 on Debian 6.x)

Comment: If you use more memory than available on your system, Linux kills applications. That Linux kill-switch is called **"OOM" (Out of Memory)**.

Comment: If you read this, G-WAN runs with *less than 1 physical GB of RAM*: http://gwan.ch/faq#cpus and on obsolete *32-bit Core Solo* CPUs. No modern machine will have lower specifications.

Comment: I should have specified: The machine is 64-bit, has a 4-core CPU, and 16GB RAM (originally.) I'm going to test with the latest update of G-WAN (4.2.7) later this evening to see if the error remains. I'll report back the results.

Comment: Can you elaborate about HOW you *"go to 9+GB of RAM"*? I mean, there's no way to have G-WAN do that without a servlet or handler.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something about G-WAN. If I load 4GBx2 + 1GBx1 memory modules (9GB of RAM) into my system, why would I need to configure G-WAN to handle that? Also, I have not tested the latest build of G-WAN that you @Gil released about a week ago. If there's something I need to config in G-WAN, let me know and I'll look into it.

Comment: We certainly NEVER invited you to "configure" G-WAN as it comes without configuration files. We merely requested you to *explain* how you are consuming those 9 GiB. I suggest that you contact G-WAN's support and give the relevant information.

Comment: I have a 4-core machine with 9GB of ram. GWAN does not start. If I take that same exact machine and rip out 1GB of ram, GWAN starts just fine. That simple. I've moved on from this problem and repurposed the machine.